# Has anyone tried replacing the View Engine with Sitecore MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore-mvc, dotliquid

I'm wondering if anyone has had any experience replacing the Razor view engine with another one such as DotLiquid or Spark in Sitecore MVC?

We are looking at this to try and stop the wasted effort in going from static front-end prototype to dynamic CMS template and so we can work off the one source. Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've replaced it with classic MVC once with the SparkView engine, back in version 2.0.
Works fine and then fact that you're using MVC with Sitecore should not affect it.

I'm questioning the need for replacing the view engine though.
If your goal is to use the same front-end templates for your Sitecore application, why not go with a front-end solution that renders the Razor tags for you?
There are JavaScript solutions out there that can do this.

Comment: Razor is basically like PHP, it's just html with interpolated C# code. So you will never be able to properly use Razor in anything other than a c# environment, Which means you can't use it on Linux or MacOSx workstations... Liquid however has template engines that work on a variety of environments.